# How can we implement an ApacheConnectionProvider that goes through a proxy?

Tags: java, proxy, jersey, client, jersey-2.0

I had implemented an *HttpUrlConnectorProvider* that goes through a *proxy*.
I want to implement the same using **ApacheConnectionProvider**.
Are there any suggestions on how we can implement this and if it's possible or not?

**HttpUrlConnectorProvider Code:**

```
final URI uri = new URI(someProxy);
final HttpUrlConnectorProvider customConnectorProvider = new HttpUrlConnectorProvider();

customConnectorProvider.connectionFactory(
    new ConnectionFactory() {

      @Override
      public HttpURLConnection getConnection(java.net.URL url) throws IOException {
        Proxy proxy =
            new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort()));
        return (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
      }
    });
```